# Flex - Zooming in/out browser

Tags: html, apache-flex, zooming

I'm developing a new Flex app that's in the middle of an html page.

I want to be able to achieve what this website achieves http://monicaruggieri.com/ when zooming in and out in the browser. It makes the container smaller but does not rescale the swf file.

Presently my app, scales and it looks ugly. I want it to basically not scale and just make everything smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this is achieved but if you use chrome and hit ctrl+shift+j you'll get the developer panel, switch over to the elements section if it isn't already selected, you can then expand the nodes and see that there's a div called floatFlash in there, click on it and on the right you can see all the styles that are applied to that div, I'd say in all likelihood if you were to copy those styles onto your container you'll get the same behavior.

Comment: Also to be honest I think the way it changes size on that site is ugly I get a massively pixelated looking graphic when zooming in though I can't offer a better solution without writing quite a bit of custom code (also her mobile site is a bit too much face :).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the [stage's scaleMode property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html).